# In FFmpeg, if input files include JPG, encoding mp4 will "fail," but if I change the JPG to PNG, encoding succeeds

Tags: ffmpeg

I am encoding an mp4 video using the FFmpeg command line with a somewhat long command. In this example there are 37 input streams, most of which are PNG files.

The command below works exactly as I expect it will. After untold hours of troubleshooting, I can reproduce an encoding problem if one of the files is JPG instead of PNG. Or, more accurately, I have the encoding problem (described below) if I keep one of the files in its original, JPG, format, but **I can eliminate the problem and successfully encode if I convert the JPG to PNG prior to encoding**.

I know my programming ability, so **I think it is more likely that I have made an error** than that I have encountered a bug in FFmpeg. While the command works as I expect, that doesn't mean I'm using FFmpeg correctly: it only means I am able to predict the results.

## The encoding problem

FFmpeg doesn't give me an error, and the warnings don't seem related to the problem. The problem takes two forms that seem the same to me, but *might* be different. In the first form, FFmpeg will encode everything up to the JPG file, then it will repeatedly add the first frame of that part until I stop FFmpeg. After I stop the encoding, the video will play and everything is perfect until the repeated frame. In the second form, FFmpeg will start encoding, write one frame, then stop writing frames. But, FFmpeg is still running: the stats are updating and showing that the encoding "speed" is decreasing because it is not writing new frames but time is incrementing. For example:

`frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.01 bitrate=  36.0kbits/s speed=7.63e-06x`

## Dense text

When writing this question, I added the filter_complex script after writing almost everything else. That text is too dense to read without the colors and stylings of my text editor. sigh.

## FFmpeg is up-to-date

I compiled FFmpeg using [media-autobuild_suite](https://github.com/m-ab-s/media-autobuild_suite) on 3 June 2023. The -buildconf is at the end of the post. I've used this build to encode many videos.

## Everything is the same except the file format

I converted the JPG file to PNG with this command `FFmpeg -i 611.jpg -update 1 611.png` and all of the other files and commands are the same. But, that doesn't mean I used the commands correctly. FFmpeg is sometimes fault tolerant.

## Truncated command lines

The the length of the command line and the supporting text files is a little over 22,000 characters, so I can't copy and paste everything here. I'll try to include the relevant things, though.

### The command line

1. The second file is 611.jpg when the problem happens. In this case, it will stop writing after one frame. If I put a jpg in the spot occupied by "images\avatars\7_bg.png," FFmpeg will write most of the frames but stop at that file.
2. I preserved my use of quotes and double quotes.
3. All paths are as shown: relative.
4. Input streams are in order, so the stream indexes are accurate.

(Line returns inserted for readablity)

```
FFmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel level+error -stats -y 
-an -i images\progress_bar.mp4 
-stream_loop -1 -framerate 60 -t 2000ms -i images\bg\611.png 
-stream_loop -1 -framerate 60 -t 2000ms -i images\box_level.png 
-an -f concat -i 1.FFconcat 
-an -f concat -i 2.FFconcat 
[4 other files]

-an -f concat -i 7.FFconcat 
-itsoffset 27000ms -stream_loop -1 -framerate 60 -t 5100ms -i images\supporter\4237.png 
-itsoffset 61100ms -stream_loop -1 -framerate 60 -t 5100ms -i images\supporter\6787.png 
[16 other files]

-itsoffset 640800ms -stream_loop -1 -framerate 60 -t 5100ms -i images\supporter\3699.png 
-itsoffset 674900ms -stream_loop -1 -framerate 60 -t 5100ms -i images\supporter\2144.png 

-an -itsoffset 180000ms -i images\engage\like_1.mp4 

-stream_loop -1 -framerate 60 -t 8500ms -i images\bg_plain\LevelsEvent.png 
-stream_loop -1 -framerate 60 -t 8500ms -i images\avatars\avatar_frame.png 
-stream_loop -1 -framerate 60 -t 8500ms -i images\avatars\7.png 
-stream_loop -1 -framerate 60 -t 8500ms -i images\avatars\7_bg.png 

-stream_loop -1 -framerate 60 -t 6000ms -i images\bg\Microworld_v.png 

-stream_loop -1 -t 727567ms -i Music\27min.aac 

-filter_complex_script 0.filter_complex 

-r 60 -g 30 -crf 17 -fpre FFpresets\youtube.ffpreset -profile:v high 
-x264opts bframes=2:colormatrix=bt709 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset slow 

-map 36:a -codec:a copy -map "[3_CONCATENATED_36]" 

-threads 0 "publish\output file.mp4"
```

### n.FFconcat

The FFconcat files are similar. In this example, each file has between 6 and 16 entries, but I've made videos that used over 100. This is the first 2 of 16 entries from 6.FFconcat.

```
ffconcat version 1.0
file '6.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:00.017
outpoint 00:00:06.517
duration 00:00:06.500
file '6.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:13.350
outpoint 00:00:27.050
duration 00:00:13.700
```

### 0.filter_complex

1. I've removed more than 8,000 of the 11,000 characters.
2. I'm not claiming that I used the filters correctly.
3. I wrote some inline explanations.

```
[1]scale=1080:1920:flags=lanczos,setdar=9/16[TRANSITION_BG];
[TRANSITION_BG][2]overlay=x=0-overlay_w/2+540:y=0-overlay_h/2+640[TRANSITION_BOX];

[TRANSITION_BOX]split=7[TRANSITION_BOX_1][TRANSITION_BOX_2][TRANSITION_BOX_3]
[TRANSITION_BOX_4][TRANSITION_BOX_5][TRANSITION_BOX_6][TRANSITION_BOX_7];

[TRANSITION_BOX_1]drawtext=fontcolor=0xffffff:text='Level 1':fontsize=116
:fontfile=/full/path/fonts/font_file.ttf
:x=540-(text_w/2):y=640-(text_h/2)[LEVEL_1];
[LEVEL_1]fade=in:0:30[INTRO_1];

INTRO_1 will be concatenated later

[3]crop=out_w=1080:out_h=1920[1_MIDDLE];
[3]crop=out_w=1080:out_h=190+60:x=0:y=120-60[1_TOP];
[1_MIDDLE][1_TOP]overlay=x=0-overlay_w/2+0+overlay_w/2
:y=0-overlay_h/2+0+overlay_h/2[1_MIDDLE_1_TOP];

[3]crop=out_w=1080:out_h=210+40:x=0:y=in_h-210-80[1_BOTTOM];
[1_MIDDLE_1_TOP][1_BOTTOM]overlay=x=0-overlay_w/2+0+overlay_w/2
:y=0-overlay_h/2+main_h-overlay_h+overlay_h/2[1_VIDEO_OVERLAYS];

[1_VIDEO_OVERLAYS]fade=in:start_time=0:duration=0.5,setdar=9/16[VIDEO_BASE_1];

VIDEO_BASE_1 will be concatenated later 

6 more sections of TRANSITION_BOX_n to VIDEO_BASE_n corresponding to n.FFconcat

concatenate everything up to here
[INTRO_1][VIDEO_BASE_1][INTRO_2][VIDEO_BASE_2][INTRO_3][VIDEO_BASE_3]
[INTRO_4][VIDEO_BASE_4][INTRO_5][VIDEO_BASE_5][INTRO_6][VIDEO_BASE_6]
[INTRO_7][VIDEO_BASE_7]concat=n=14:v=1:a=0[14_CONCATENATED_10];

20 image overlays and 1 video overlay on the concatenated video

[10]fade=type=in:alpha=1:start_time=27000ms:duration=500ms,
fade=type=out:alpha=1:start_time=31600ms:duration=500ms[FADE_10];
[14_CONCATENATED_10][FADE_10]overlay=x=0-overlay_w/2+463:y=0-overlay_h/2+1775
:enable='between(t,27000/1000,32100/1000)'[SUPPORTER_10];

18 more sections of stream index n to SUPPORTER_n
Notice the incrementing start_time and :enable between

[29]fade=type=in:alpha=1:start_time=674900ms:duration=500ms,
fade=type=out:alpha=1:start_time=679500ms:duration=500ms[FADE_29];
[SUPPORTER_28][FADE_29]overlay=x=0-overlay_w/2+463:y=0-overlay_h/2+1775
:enable='between(t,674900/1000,680000/1000)'[SUPPORTER_29];

1 video overlay

[30]colorkey=color=0x00d800:similarity=0.3,
scale=1024:576:flags=lanczos[LIKE_30];
[SUPPORTER_29][LIKE_30]overlay=x=0-overlay_w/2+540
:y=0-overlay_h/2+-140+overlay_h/2
:enable='between(t,180000/1000,184000/1000)'[THUMB_30];

THUMB_30 is all of the overlays on all of the videos to this point
THUMB_30 will be concatenated at the end

[31]crop=out_w=1080:out_h=1920,setdar=9/16[AWARD_BG];
[AWARD_BG][32]overlay=x=0-overlay_w/2+540:y=0-overlay_h/2+376[AWARD_FRAME];
[AWARD_FRAME][33]overlay=x=0-overlay_w/2+540:y=0-overlay_h/2+376[AWARD_AVATAR];
[34]pad=w=1080:h=1080:color=0x4d5e6e:x=(out_w-in_w)/2:y=(out_h-in_h)/2[POSTCARD];
[AWARD_AVATAR][POSTCARD]overlay=x=0-overlay_w/2+540:y=0-overlay_h/2+1290[AWARD_POSTCARD];
[AWARD_POSTCARD]fade=type=in:start_time=0:duration=0.5[AWARD];

AWARD will be concatenated at the end

[35]scale=1080:1920:flags=lanczos,
fade=type=in:start_time=0:duration=0.5:color=black[ENDSCREEN];
[ENDSCREEN]drawtext=fontcolor=0x265b7d:textfile=/full/path/text_UTF-8.txt
:fontsize=64:fontfile=:fontfile=/full/path/fonts/different_font_file.ttf
:box=1:boxcolor=0xf9f9f9:boxborderw=32:x=540-(text_w/2):y=520-(text_h/2)
:enable='between(t,1500/1000,6000/1000)',setdar=9/16[QTY_VIDEOS];

[THUMB_30][AWARD][QTY_VIDEOS]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0[3_CONCATENATED_36];
```

### youtube.ffpreset

1. I have encoded over 3000 videos with this preset file, but I'm not claiming it is correct.
2. I don't think the following detail is the cause of the problem because of 3000 videos, but I suspect that this detail is redundant or incorrect. In this preset file, I write "bf=2" and on the command line I write "-x264opts bframes=2". Redundant? Conflicting? I sincerely don't know.

```
vcodec=libx264
movflags=faststart
field_order=progressive
bf=2
flags=cgop
coder=1
colorspace=bt709
color_trc=bt709
color_primaries=bt709
```

## loglevel 24, warning

I only have a log at level 24, warning. This is from the file that encoded successfully.

```
[aac @ 0000024c57dea940] [warning] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
[swscaler @ 0000024c6d3c0040] [swscaler @ 0000024c6d3d5040] [warning] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to argb.
14 more warnings
[swscaler @ 0000024c6d3c0040] [swscaler @ 0000024c6d3ef000] [warning] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to argb.
[concat @ 0000024c57038cc0] [warning] DTS 86097 < 174117 out of order
3 more @ 0000024c57038cc0
[out_0_1 @ 0000024c6997bc00] [warning] 100 buffers queued in out_0_1, something may be wrong.
[concat @ 0000024c57038480] [warning] DTS 116824 < 174116 out of order
10 more @ 0000024c57038480
[concat @ 0000024c57038740] [warning] DTS 166496 < 174939 out of order
14 more @ 0000024c57038740
51 more @ three different addresses
They seem to be perfectly correlated with the 7 command line input streams
"-f concat -i n.FFconcat"
```

The unsuccessful encoding is much shorter because it only wrote one frame to the file.

```
[aac @ 000001c64988c580] [warning] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
[swscaler @ 000001c65b2c5f00] [warning] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000001c65d9f7040] [swscaler @ 000001c65da04000] [warning] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to argb.
[swscaler @ 000001c65d9f7040] [swscaler @ 000001c65da18f40] [warning] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to argb.
[swscaler @ 000001c65d9f7040] [swscaler @ 000001c65da2de40] [warning] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to argb.
[swscaler @ 000001c65d9f7040] [swscaler @ 000001c65da42d80] [warning] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to argb.
[swscaler @ 000001c65e50ddc0] [warning] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000001c65e50ddc0] [warning] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000001c65e50ddc0] [warning] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000001c65b8770c0] [swscaler @ 000001c661566900] [warning] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to argb.
[swscaler @ 000001c65b8770c0] [swscaler @ 000001c65d9f7040] [warning] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to argb.
[swscaler @ 000001c65b8770c0] [swscaler @ 000001c65da0a040] [warning] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to argb.
[swscaler @ 000001c65b8770c0] [swscaler @ 000001c65da1d080] [warning] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to argb.
[swscaler @ 000001c65b8770c0] [swscaler @ 000001c661566900] [warning] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to argb.
[swscaler @ 000001c65b8770c0] [swscaler @ 000001c65d9f7040] [warning] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to argb.
[swscaler @ 000001c65b8770c0] [swscaler @ 000001c65da0a040] [warning] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to argb.
[swscaler @ 000001c65b8770c0] [swscaler @ 000001c65da1d080] [warning] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to argb.
[swscaler @ 000001c65b8770c0] [swscaler @ 000001c661566900] [warning] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to argb.
[swscaler @ 000001c65b8770c0] [swscaler @ 000001c65d9f7040] [warning] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to argb.
[swscaler @ 000001c65b8770c0] [swscaler @ 000001c65da0a040] [warning] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to argb.
[swscaler @ 000001c65b8770c0] [swscaler @ 000001c65da1d080] [warning] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to argb.
```

## FFmpeg -buildconf

```
libavutil      58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
libavcodec     60. 16.100 / 60. 16.100
libavformat    60.  5.100 / 60.  5.100
libavdevice    60.  2.100 / 60.  2.100
libavfilter     9.  8.101 /  9.  8.101
libswscale      7.  3.100 /  7.  3.100
libswresample   4. 11.100 /  4. 11.100
libpostproc    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100

configuration:
--pkg-config=pkgconf
--cc='ccache gcc'
--cxx='ccache g++'
--ld='ccache g++'
--extra-cxxflags=-fpermissive
--extra-cflags=-Wno-int-conversion
--disable-autodetect
--enable-d3d11va
--enable-dxva2
--enable-iconv
--enable-lzma
--enable-zlib
--enable-sdl2
--enable-ffnvcodec
--enable-nvdec
--enable-libmp3lame
--enable-libopus
--enable-libvorbis
--enable-libvpx
--enable-libx264
--enable-libx265
--enable-libdav1d
--enable-libaom
--disable-debug
--enable-libfdk-aac
--enable-fontconfig
--enable-libass
--enable-libfreetype
--enable-libmysofa
--enable-libopencore-amrnb
--enable-libopencore-amrwb
--enable-libopenjpeg
--enable-libsoxr
--enable-libwebp
--enable-gpl
--enable-libtesseract
--enable-openal
--enable-libopenh264
--enable-openssl
--extra-libs=-liconv
--enable-version3
--enable-nonfree
--extra-cflags=-DAL_LIBTYPE_STATIC
--extra-cflags='-IC:/mabs/local64/include'
--extra-cflags='-IC:/mabs/local64/include/AL'
```

Comment: Rerun with `-report`. Upload and link to report.

Comment: Successful log, 75 mb, https://mega.nz/file/HFFFnLJI#gONGNZ9zLxe6iC3V9Fjl1E5SS_svy7zLtyk8_dBGzWk
Failed log, 0.6 mb https://mega.nz/file/yUMQDITb#2tUOKOioed1HpkWX6hkyorsUZWQjTZXQ6LaUN7tR_RA
(Note to people in the future: these links will be disabled.)